# Jenkins - NullPointerException when calling parameterized job

Tags: jenkins

I´m assembling two Jenkins Nodes to build a product of our company. The product has an Android application and an iPhone application. I have a Windows installation of Jenkins that I´m using as my master and I´ll use to build all sort of projects (.Net, Java, Android) and I have a MAC OS X Slave that I´m using to build iOS projects.

In the MAC jenkins I have the project configured and it is building my application.

I want to create a job at the Windows that will trigger both the Android project on the local server and the iOS project on the slave.

In the MAC Jenkins I installed the Parameterized Trigger Plugin and marked my build as parameterized. When I try to build my project using:

> buildWithParameters?delay=0

I get the following exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:796)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:249)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:686)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1494)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:132)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:123)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1474)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:533)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:949)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1011)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty.buildWithParameters(ParametersDefinitionProperty.java:182)
    at jenkins.model.ParameterizedJobMixIn.doBuildWithParameters(ParameterizedJobMixIn.java:218)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.doBuildWithParameters(AbstractProject.java:1780)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor878.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:298)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:161)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:96)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:121)
    at     org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
    ... 48 more
```

If I try to add a dummy string parameter on my configuration and call it with

> buildWithParameters?delay=0&a=a

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at hudson.plugins.parameterizedtrigger.ProjectSpecificParameterValuesActionTransform.getParameterDefinitionsMap(ProjectSpecificParameterValuesActionTransform.java:46)
at hudson.plugins.parameterizedtrigger.ProjectSpecificParameterValuesActionTransform.transformParametersAction(ProjectSpecificParameterValuesActionTransform.java:28)
at hudson.plugins.parameterizedtrigger.ProjectSpecificParametersActionFactory.getProjectSpecificBuildActions(ProjectSpecificParametersActionFactory.java:33)
at hudson.plugins.parameterizedtrigger.BuildTriggerConfig.getBuildActions(BuildTriggerConfig.java:351)
at hudson.plugins.parameterizedtrigger.BuildTriggerConfig.perform3(BuildTriggerConfig.java:419)
at hudson.plugins.parameterizedtrigger.BlockableBuildTriggerConfig.perform3(BlockableBuildTriggerConfig.java:66)
at hudson.plugins.parameterizedtrigger.TriggerBuilder.perform(TriggerBuilder.java:88)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:782)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:205)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:162)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1738)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
```

Since I can´t trigger this build I can´t create a job on my master to build the iPhone application.

If more information is needed I´ll be glad to provide it.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same stack trace you received when you passed a dummy parameter in.

I was passing parameters from one job to another and had marked the triggered job as parameterised assuming that something would go wrong if I tried to pass parameters to an un-parameterised job but didn't define any parameters.

Unmarking the "This build is parameterized" checkbox solved this problem for me.